# How to place textview on right and left of layout?

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I want to place a textview on the right of a layout and on the left of a layout, but they keep stacking ontop of each other:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lefttext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Symbol"/>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/righttext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Price"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Symbol"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Price"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Why are you specifying 0dip for the height on these?

For symbols on sides:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Symbol"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Price"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And done with a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Code"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_text"
        android:gravity="right"     
        android:text="Company Name"
        />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: any way to make symbol be on the far left and price be on the far right?

Comment: Yes, just adjust the gravity setting to whatever you would like. I've added an example above. (I also added a small amount of padding, so that they aren't pressed up against the sides)

Comment: The right_text doesn't seem to gravitate towards the right, check out my screenshot: http://cl.ly/786ff7d72c99537d190b

Comment: Are you using this in a ListView?

Comment: Yes I am using this in a ListView

Comment: Try it like the one I just added. A RelativeLayout might work better for you here.

Comment: that looks more like it! how can I specify the height of each row to be larger?

Comment: Hmm, I can't remember the elegant way right now...but you should be able to add android:paddingTop="some number" and android:paddingBottom="some number" to your RelativeLayout, which should do the trick, I believe.

Comment: thanks for the help! I posted a new question, because I added in another column, but am having trouble aligning it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586235/how-to-create-column-like-layout-for-listview-rows

Comment: I'll try to answer that later if no one has answered it yet. (I'm at work, no Eclipse here for me. :( )

Just from a quick look, though, from your comments. Each TableRow will make a new "line", but the row can contain multiple columns by adding Views. So <TableRow><TextView/><TextView/></TableRow>, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on view inside `RelaytiveLayout` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Symbol"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="Price"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively you can use `TableLayout` with `stretchColumn` set to stretch the second column to the size of parent.

Answer (score 4):

With LinearLayout, just put an empty TextView with the weight between them:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lefttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Symbol"/>
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/righttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Price"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Except, it's better to put not a TextView but a View: <View ... android:layout_weight="1"/>